# Dual boot : Ubuntu detects Windows Boot Manager instead of Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS alongside Windows 7.

Howewer, during installation it detects Windows Boot Manager instead of Windows 7 so I have an option : Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager.

Is it a problem or it is safe to proceed?

Thank you very much for help!

[My partition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjvEO.jpg)

Comment: Did you use something like EasyBCD?

Comment: No,  I simply created unallocated space on Windows by Windows partitioning tool for Ubuntu.

Comment: To be safe, you could just format that empty space as ext4, go into its properties from that window and tell it to make mount it as /. That'll install Ubuntu to it

Comment: But Ubuntu should be installed automatically on that free space, no? I am not very familiar with partitioning, so I would prefer doing it the common way if there is not a reasonable risk of messing up something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it's perfectly safe. I dualboot Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as well. 
You get Windows Boot Manager because the boot partition of Windows was installed in another partition. (`sda2` as shown in the picture below)

[image]

Once you select the boot manager, it will ask you to select Windows 7 and then boot it up.

Comment: Thank you, I have successfully installed it.  One more question :  is it safe to hibernate the operating systems?

Comment: It's safe to hibernate Ubuntu as the ext4 file system is not visible to windows anyway. Unfortunately, hibernating Win7 will lock the drives visible on Windows and hence you will not be able to access them from Linux. If you are fine with this, then you can do so.

Comment: And how it will affect functionnig of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu is unaffected

Comment: Aaah of course, drives, I read drivers :P Thanks.